# How come text can't be selected in react-select's demo?

Tags: reactjs

This is a question I've been pondering, how does react-select prohibit text selection? Specifically in the first demo. I don't see a css property that disallows this in the DOM

[image]

Comment: Because the select box is a different element then were the actual 'red' located. Use the DOM inspector in your browser to see the elements

Comment: the 'red' is a child of the select box though?